# Is it a good idea to use the motor voltage as a source for a logic regulated voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, stepper-motor

I'm creating a circuit for controlling a NEMA17 step motor with 1.7A per phase. This motor will be driven with +12V. The logic part of the circuit will use +5V though.

At the beginning, I was planning to use a different voltage source for each part of the circuit (motor power and logic), but then I was thinking if it'll be a good idea to use the +12V that goes to the motor to also be used together with an AMS1117 (5V) to provide a regulated voltage to the logic circuit like the image below where **VMM** is the power of the step motor.

[image: VMM is the voltage for the step motor]

Is it a good idea or not? My concern is about the stability of the output regulated voltage from the AMS1117 when the motor is running even though I added the electrolytic capacitor at the output as recommended by the datasheet.

I think it's good to tell that the 12V comes from a source like this one:

[image]

Can you guys tell me your opinion/experiences about that? Have you already created a circuit like that?

Comment: If you back drive the stepper while the power supply is off, your electronics will start up...

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ChrisStratton. I agree with you. I didn't notice that before. However it's important to say that the step motor is connected to a DRV8825. Do you still think this is a problem? If so, how could I prevent that?

Comment: It was mostly an observation, if it is a *problem* depends on equipment and circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec you care about here is called "input ripple rejection". This is usually expressed in dB as \$\frac{ΔV_{in}}{ΔV_{out}}\$ under specified conditions.

In this case, [the datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) (ripple rejection is on page 3) specifies that, using a 22μF tantalum output capacitor and a 6.5V input voltage, with 1A output, ripple rejection at 120Hz is guaranteed to be at least 60 dB; in other words, the output voltage will vary by at most 0.1% of the input variation. This doesn't tell you the full story, and the ripple at different frequencies or with different input voltages or output currents may not be rejected as well, but you can expect it to handle input ripple fairly well.

As for dynamic stability, page 4 of the datasheet says that a 22μF tantalum output capacitor guarantees stability under any operating conditions. If you're not using a tantalum cap, anything with similar specs (say, a low-ESR aluminum electrolytic, for example) will probably have similar performance. It also says that larger output capacitances can be used, so 22μF can be treated as a minimum if you like.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you by giving me a so detailed answer!

Comment: Don't overlook what @ChrisStratton said in the comments above, either. That could potentially be a problem!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enough overhead on the PSU to drive the motor so it can maintain the desired voltage.
Additionally I'd increase the capacitor on the input of the 5V regulator to minimize ripple. As long as you're just using the 5V for logic I don't see a big issue, if you use it to generate reference voltages for high precision measurements the story would be different.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciated it. What do you mean with PSU?

Comment: PSU = Power Supply Unit, providing your 12V